# Why doesn't my header scroll to the right?

Tags: html, css

I'm just making a simple header, a div element with this css:

.header

```
{
position: absolute;
width: 1000px;
height: 50px;
background: #000000;
left: 50%;
top: 0px;
margin: 0 0 0 -500px;
}
```

Everything's perfect, but when I resize my window to a smaller width than 1000px, a scrollbar appears(like it should), but I cant' scroll to the left. So a part of my header isn't shown and can't be scrolled to.

Comment: Bigger question.... Why do you want your header to scroll, why not make it responsive??

Comment: It sounds like you have an overflow problem, but without seeing more code it would be hard to determine that

Comment: @BenM http://imgur.com/18PU4zd that's what it looks like for me, and i can't scroll to the left.

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus Okay, it fixed the problem with the scrolling, but if I leave out the left:50%; part the header isn't in the middle.

Comment: @user2555857 can you provide a fiddle? Make sure to remove the properties **position, left & top**.

Answer (score 1):

What you're experiencing is actually **correct behavour**, because you're centering 
the `header` using a negative `margin-left`.
Instead of your current approach, you can use `margin:0 auto` to display it horizontally centered:

```
header {
    display:block;
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Make sure to remove <s>`position:absolute`</s>.

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Y4jv/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: The position:absolute should be a position:fixed because I want the header to scroll down with the page. But if I add the position:fixed i have the same problem as before.

Comment: `position:fixed` causes your header to stay **fixed** if the client scrolls. If you want it to scroll with the page, `position:absolute` should be fine. I've [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Y4jv/3/) to visualize it.